# Timeout doesn't work in HttpWebRequest - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I faced with a URL that doesn't response.

How can I provide Timeout in my code or in web.config.

Current code should to stop after 2 seconds but it doesn't.

```
HttpWebRequest req = null;
HttpWebResponse resp = null;

req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.tp.com");
//req.Method = "HEAD"; 
req.Method = "GET";
req.KeepAlive = false;
req.Timeout = 2000;
req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
req.ReadWriteTimeout = 2000;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Analysis; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: What is the Proxy Setting?  If proxy is enabled the code will wait 30 seconds for a timeout.

Comment: @jdweng I not using Proxy Setting. anyway what should I do for 2 seconds timeout

Comment: Try : req.Proxy = null;

Comment: @jdweng It doesn't help.